# Eclipse will not run my code and the editor shows no code errors at all

Tags: java, eclipse

The code was running just fine until i tried to re-position a JLabel and although it shows no errors in my code it refuses to run it and gives me the following error... I am trying to move the label to the upper left corner of the JFrame window and the method i used to do so should be perfectly fine. At least to my knowledge. [Beginner Java Dev]

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: verticalAlignment
at javax.swing.JLabel.checkVerticalKey(JLabel.java:627)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.java:713)
at io.Arimore.Launcher.createAndShowGUI(Launcher.java:27)
at io.Arimore.Launcher.access$0(Launcher.java:13)
at io.Arimore.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:46)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Code:

```
package io.Arimore;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/* FrameDemo.java requires no other files. */
public class Launcher {

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize(); //Gets the user screen size
    int scrnHigh = d.height; //Pulls out the High
    int scrnWide = d.width; //Pulls out the Wide
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome to Arimore.io");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("Arimore.io - v0.01A");
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    int quatrainsY = (d.height / 2);
    int elabelH = (0 - quatrainsY);
    int elabelW = (0 - (d.width / 2));
    emptyLabel.setVerticalAlignment(elabelH);
    emptyLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(elabelW);
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();

    //setSize(scrnWide *9/10, scrnHigh *9/10);//sets screen to 0.9 size
    frame.setSize(scrnWide, scrnHigh);//sets screen to FULL size
    //setLocation(scrnWide *1/20, scrnHigh *1/20);//CENTER it for 9/10th size
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);//
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You're passing a negative value to `setVerticalAlignment`. That method (per the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setVerticalAlignment(int))) accepts 3 `int` constants defined in `SwingConstants` (`TOP`, `CENTER` **or** `BOTTOM`).

Comment: so in order for me to move it to the top left what would I have to do

Comment: nvm tzimhoch covered it

Answer (score 3):

JLabel.setVerticalAlignment takes an int, but the int values should be JLabel.TOP, JLabel.MIDDLE, or JLabel.BOTTOM.

Also, JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment will take JLabel.LEFT, JLabel.CENTER, and JLabel.RIGHT.

Any other values will cause an illegal argument exception.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU IT WORKED!! I'll accept the answer soon. right now it wont let me...